# Imported python class does not have access to loaded package, Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have written several functions which uses tensorflow and stored them in a separate file called modelDefinition.py. Currently I'm working on a notebook under the same directory as modelDefinition.py. I imported tensorflow as tf in my notebook and tried to call functions defined in modelDefinition.py. I got the following error:

```
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

Here's what's inside modelDefinition.py

```
def modelDef(ckpt_dir,l2,dr,img_size=80,n_bands=3,nf=32):
    regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2)
    initializer = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()
    # model definitions
    ...

    return model
```

Here's what I have in my notebook

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from modelDefinition import *

# Create model and load pre-trained weights 
model = modelDef(ckpt_dir='checkpoints',l2=0.01,dr=0.1)
```

Here's the full Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 2
      1 # Create model and load pre-trained weights 
----> 2 model = modelDef(ckpt_dir='checkpoints',l2=0.01,dr=0.1)


File D:\Data\Yale University\2023SP\Deep Learning Theory and Applications\Final_proj\modelDef.py:103, in modelDef(ckpt_dir, l2, dr, img_size, n_bands, nf)
    102 def modelDef(ckpt_dir,l2,dr,img_size=80,n_bands=3,nf=32):
--> 103     regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2)
    104     initializer = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()
    105     common_args = {"kernel_initializer": initializer}

NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf` should be inside modelDefinition.py. not in notebook level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must import tensorflow module in modelDefinition.py file, i am not sure if you did that.